# How to count total pages of multipile word files using dir command?

Tags: microsoft-word, cmd.exe, dir

I have folder with about 1,000 MS-word files. Apart from Name, Size and Type column, I have "Pages", which is show me how many pages each file contains. How do I count how many pages I have in my folder in total? If I can copy the Pages column with dir cmd to text file, and copy to Excel - I can sum the numbers.

Comment: [How Can I Get a Total Page Count for All the Word Documents in a Folder?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2006/09/07/how-can-i-get-a-total-page-count-for-all-the-word-documents-in-a-folder/)